how to merge dataframes in r only for rows which equal a specific value in a different column
I have 2 data frames in R.
Data frame 1 (df_1) comprises many columns, but only 3 are relevant here:
Problem         |Service_Time | Imputed_Problem
----------------------------------------------
A               |    3.5      |      NA 
B               |    1.6      |      NA
C               |    2.8      |      NA
D               |    NA       |      B

Where the problem equals D, that means that the person left without being seen (probably because the queue was too long). The problem was not registered and there is no service time.
I want to understand demand and therefore want to include these people in my dataset based on what their problem might have been and the associated service time if they had not left without being seen. I have imputed the problem for people who left without being seen by randomly assigning a problem (A, B or C) to all cases where problem == D based on the rate at which each problem appears in the population.
Where the observation is a "real" problem, I have the service time for that case. Where the problem has been imputed (here where unrecorded problem (D) has been assigned B), I want to assign the average service time for that problem in a new column called "Imputed_Service_Time".
I have created a data frame (df_2) which gives the average service time for each of the 3 problems.
Problem | Average_Service_Time
----------------------
A       |  3.2
B       |  4.2
C       |  1.7

I have created a new column in df_1 called "Imputed_Service_Time" which is an exact copy of the column "Service_Time".
How do I import the "Average_Service_Time" value for the corresponding "Imputed_Problem" column ONLY where the observation's value in column "Problem" is "D"?
I have tried the following:
merged_df <- merge(df_1, df_2, by.x = "Imputed_Problem", by.y = "Problem", all.x = TRUE)

merged_df$Imputed_Service_Time <- ifelse(is.na(merged_df$Service_Time), merged_df$Average_Service_Time, merged_df$Service_Time)


But I get the following error message:
Error in ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos] : 
  replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(yes, length.out = len) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL


Please add an expected output based on your given example. Maybe merge(df1, df2, by.x = "Imputed_Problem", by.y = "Problem")?

You can try the following:
library(dplyr)

left_join(df_1, df_2, by=c("Imputed_Problem" = "Problem")) %>% 
  mutate(Imputed_Service_Time = case_when(
    is.na(Imputed_Problem)~Service_Time,
    .default = Average_Service_Time
  ))

Output:
 Problem Service_Time Imputed_Problem Average_Service_Time Imputed_Service_Time
1       A          3.5            <NA>                   NA                  3.5
2       B          1.6            <NA>                   NA                  1.6
3       C          2.8            <NA>                   NA                  2.8
4       D           NA               B                  4.2                  4.2

or, credit to Jon Spring, you can use coalesce()
left_join(df_1, df_2, by=c("Imputed_Problem" = "Problem")) %>% 
   mutate(Imputed_Service_Time = coalesce(Service_Time, Average_Service_Time))


Another option could be mutate(Imputed_Service_Time = coalesce(Service_Time, Average_Service_Time))
